# Oracle pivoting unknown number of column before execution time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have something like this:

```
id  cod
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   d
2   e
3   f
3   g
```

and i need something like this:

```
id  cod 1   cod 2   cod 3
1   a       b       c
2   d       e   
3   f       g
```

you understand that there is no way to know how many column oracle will have to generate before the execution time.

Comment: why for `id=1`, cod `a`, comes under `cod1` not `cod2` or `cod3`, you need to specify that logic. I mean with which logic you list cod rows as columns? getting such results is possible but you need to clarify the question.

Comment: you could either pivot XML,or use dynamic SQL inside pl/sql to first query the source table for number of columns you'll need in the result, then form the query and execute immediate.

Comment: I need to know what are the cod associated to every id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use procedure p_pivot, code below. It dynamically builds view v_test based on your table.
Then you can select from this view like here:

```
Connected to Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 

SQL> execute p_pivot;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select * from v_test;

        ID COD1  COD2  COD3
---------- ----- ----- -----
         1 a     b     c
         2 d     e     
         3 f     g
```

Procedure (please change table name from `test` to your table name in code):

```
create or replace procedure p_pivot is
  v_cols number;
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
  select max(cnt) into v_cols
    from (select count(1) cnt from test group by id);

  v_sql := 
  'create or replace view v_test as 
  with t as (select row_number() over (partition by id order by cod) rn, test.* from test)
  select id';

  for i in 1..v_cols
  loop
    v_sql := v_sql || ', max(decode(rn, '||i||', cod)) cod'||i;
  end loop;
  v_sql := v_sql || ' from t group by id';
  execute immediate v_sql;
end p_pivot;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is NO way how to do that. Oracle HAS to know the number of columns at the moment when it is compiling the query.

Imagine that you create a view using such a query. The view would have different number of columns each time you look at it.

Also there should be no way how to fetch data from such a query. Because you do not know how many columns have until you evaluate all the data in the table.

Comment: Let's immagine that i want always to generate 50 columns (they would be enough): how could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use this query also.

--Creating test data

```
create table test_me(id_num  number,val varchar2(10));

insert all 

into test_me 

values(1,'a')

into test_me values (1,'b')

into test_me values (1,'c')

into test_me values (2,'d')

into test_me values (2,'e')

into test_me values (3,'f')

into test_me values (3,'g')

select 1 from dual;

select * from 

(

select id_num,val,row_number() over (partition by  id_num order by val) rn

from test_me )

pivot (max(val) for id_num in(1 as val_1,2 as val_2,3 as val_3));
```

The SQLFiddle demo is here 
[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4206f/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4206f/1)1

Comment: this query has fixed number of columns: val_1, val_2, val_3