# Oracle sql,plsql create a sql building up the variables

Tags: sql, oracle

Wonder if someone could guide me in the right direction.

I have a data table structure as below:

```
table2_type char (1)

table2_key char (40)

table2_reftype char (20)

table2_seq char (10)

table2_ref char (50)
```

and data rows like(comma separated for readability only):

```
I,123456789,typea,0000000001,abc

I,123456789,typeb,0000000002,999

I,123456789,typec,0000000003,9z9

I,123456789,typed,0000000004,zyx

I,123456789,typee,0000000005,qwe

I,987654321,typea,0000000006,bcd

I,987654321,typeb,0000000007,444
```

What I have to do at the moment to get all the table_ref values for the same table_key values is below (spaced for ease of reading):

```
select table1_bkey,

nvl((case when (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad('typea',20)) is not null then (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad('typea',20)) else (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_alt and table2_reftype = rpad('typea',20)) end),' ') as REF_A,

nvl((case when (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad('typeb',20)) is not null then (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad('typeb',20)) else (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_alt and table2_reftype = rpad('typeb',20)) end),' ') as REF_B,

nvl((case when (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad('typec',20)) is not null then (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad('typec',20)) else (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_alt and table2_reftype = rpad('typec',20)) end),' ') as REF_C,

nvl((case when (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad('typed',20)) is not null then (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad('typed',20)) else (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_alt and table2_reftype = rpad('typed',20)) end),' ') as REF_D,

nvl((case when (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad('typee',20)) is not null then (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad('typee',20)) else (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_alt and table2_reftype = rpad('typee',20)) end),' ') as REF_E

from table1 where table1_bkey = '123456789';
```

I currently could have up to 25 different table2_reftype per table2_key so I have to do 25 case statements. And if/when new table2_reftype are added I have to do new case statements.

My question, is there a way to get all the table2_reftype values per table2_key without having to do multiple case statements eg:

illustration purpose only, not to be taking literal as code in any way!!

```
while table2_key = table1_bkey

get table2_reftype 

then for each table2_reftype 

nvl((case when (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad(<table2_reftype variable>,20)) is not null then (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_bkey and table2_reftype = rpad(<table2_reftype variable>,20)) else (select table2_ref from table2 where table2_key = table1_alt and table2_reftype = rpad(<table2_reftype variable>,20)) end),' ') as REF_<table2_reftype  variable>

where table1_bkey = '123456789';
```

First post so hope I have put enough information.

Comment: By the way, are you sure you want to blank-pad all those `char` values up to the maximum? Seems like an odd business requirement.

Comment: Hi, for the moment that what I have to do until I find the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

```
select key, ref_a, ref_b, ref_c
  from (
    select table1_bkey key, table2_ref ref, trim(table2_reftype) type, 
           row_number() over (partition by table1_bkey, table2_reftype 
                              order by case table2_key when table1_bkey then 1 else 2 end) rn
      from table1
      left join table2 
        on trim(table2_reftype) in ('typea', 'typeb', 'typec')
        and table2_key in (table1_bkey, table1_alt))
  pivot (max(ref) for type in ('typea' ref_a, 'typeb' ref_b, 'typec' ref_c))
  where rn = 1
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2401017fceace3eb88ae84f31f1dcb15)</sup>**

What is going on here? I `left join`-ed both tables using your conditions. Then I assigned `rn` which depends on if match is done on base key or alternate key. Base has higher priority, so in case both were found second is removed (`where rn = 1`). Rest was easy, just pivot data for types which you hardcoded. Also please note that I trimmed `ref_type`.

This is example for 3 types, when you add new, just put it in both lists. As you can see in my dbfiddle query works, but I had to imagine some data which you did not describe (for `table1`).

In case something is wrong and you would not be able to correct / adapt this solution please edit your question and provide sample data for both tables in the form of working `create` and `insert` statements and show us desired result for this data.

You can also solve it like you described in your pseudo-code, but this requires either dynamic PLSQL, either constructing query in some other code (I did similiar things in .NET). Why? Because Oracle has to know all columns when it compiles query.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I will try out your query it is definitely simpler to maintain that my current sql.  The one thing I was trying to eliminate was the maintenance of the table2_reftype in the sql and find code that would handle when a new one is added, perhaps, like you say, plsql but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, just to say thanks again. I got the query running. I only made 1 change which was to change:

on trim(table2_reftype) in ('typea', 'typeb', 'typec')

to:

on table2_type = 'I' and table2_reftype in (select distinct(table2_reftype) from table2 where table2_type = 'I' and table2_key in (table1_bkey, table1_alt))

this eliminates 1 of the areas to maintain. Just need to find a solution that can perform a similar action on the pivot section.

Comment: This is something I wrote about. Unfortunately you cannot make pivot section working on select. It **has** to have hardcoded columns. In older Oracle versions we had to do similiar, hardcode each column separately. There are many question on SO about dynamic pivot, you may look at them, but nothing satisfactonary, simple, out of the box. I made once answer, where I created `view` in dynamic SQL, you could maybe use it, but this is workaround. Oracle has to know its columns.

Comment: Hi Ponder. I am new to SO and I have tried to find your article but with no joy. I clicked on your name and found articles you have answered but I could not find the view in dynamical sql one. Do you have a link?

Comment: Yes. Link [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032037/oracle-pivoting-unknown-number-of-column-before-execution-time), link [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179377/two-columns-pivoting-in-oracle-sql). Remember that when you dynamically create `view` all dependent Oracle objects which use it may require revalidation.

Comment: Hi Ponder. Thanks for the reply. I will have a look at the articles and see if I can get them working for me. Likely I will not get round to testing until tomorrow.